# How to retrieve a date object with Json?

Tags: java, json

I am using JSON to retrieve data from database. I have a date column in my table with type Date. I know some of you will think that this is a duplicate question but it's not all the other problems are trying to retrieve String and retrieve it to date this is the opposite.
this is the code I'm using

```
public ArrayList<Meeting> getListMeeting(String json) {
    ArrayList<Meeting> listMeetings = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        JSONParser j = new JSONParser();

        Map<String, Object> meetings = j.parseJSON(new CharArrayReader(json.toCharArray()));

        System.out.println();
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) meetings.get("meeting");


     for (Map<String, Object> obj : list) {
            Meeting m = new Meeting();
            m.setProjectName(obj.get("project_name").toString());
            m.setDescription(obj.get("description").toString());
            m.setTime(obj.get("time").toString());
            m.setDate(obj.get("date"));
          listMeetings.add(m);

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
     }
    return listMeetings;

}
```

Comment: Well what does the JSON look like? It's not really clear what the problem is. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is how the JSON looks like https://pastebin.com/kmBWhYK7    the problem is that when I try to retrieve the date an error occurs and there is no method available to retrieve data of type date

Comment: That should be *in the question*, along with a [mcve] (not just a method using several things we don't know about).

Comment: And given that it *is* a String in the JSON, it looks very much like duplicates that need to parse the string to a suitable date type...

Comment: It's not a string because using the toString method I get an error that date cannot be converted to string

Comment: Well it's a string in the JSON, as far as RFC 7159 is concerned. Maybe if you provided a [mcve] we'd be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is a represented as a string in your json. Use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse/format your string.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date = null;
try {
  date = sourceFormat.parse(jsonObj.getString("date"));
} 
catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```